# How to import all global Vue components in single file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a pretty big Vuejs app. I had imported all my components in the app.js file globally. It's working just fine but for a better structure, I want to separate all my component imports in a single other file.
Is it possible?
Here is my app.js file example:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('loading', require('./components/global-components/Loading.vue').default);
Vue.component('carousel', require('./components/global-components/Carousel.vue').default);
Vue.component('dropdown', require('./components/global-components/Dropdown.vue').default);
Vue.component('tab', require('./components/global-components/Tab.vue').default);
...
...
...
...
More than 50 components here.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can safely make a **globalComponents.js**

where are you doing yours

```
Vue.component ('loading', require ('./ components / global-components / Loading.vue'). Default);
```

and in the main.js or app.js you do

```
import 'path/to/globalComponents.js'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did this before creating this issue but didn't work.

Comment: thisi is the correct approach, what is the problem?

Comment: I got an error that you didn't register components correctly in my console for all components.

Comment: are you sure you're importing the globalComponents file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply import the file and bind it to the app's global property.

```
import rules from  "@/composables/validation-rules";
const app = createApp(App);
app.config.globalProperties.rules = rules;
```